# Reset DOM Table on Form Submit

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in my HTML file:

```
<form class="search-form">
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input type="text" id="company" name="company" required />
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="date" id="from" name="from" required />
    <label for="from">To</label>
    <input type="date" id="to" name="to" required />
    <button>Search</button>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <h1>Search Result:</h1>

  <table class="content-table" id="dataTable">
    <!-- here goes our data! -->
  </table>
```

I am making a request to server on from submit. I receive JSON response and I have a JS code to present it as a table in DOM. Every time I search for data the old data still lives in the DOM. I want to clear the table entirely and fill with new data on search. How can I do that? No JQUERY please. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: So, you just need to clear the innerHTML of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will keep the table itself but clear anything inside the table  tags.

```js
 document.getElementById("dataTable").innerHTML = "";
```

```html
<form class="search-form">
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input type="text" id="company" name="company" required />
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="date" id="from" name="from" required />
    <label for="from">To</label>
    <input type="date" id="to" name="to" required />
    <button>Search</button>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <h1>Search Result:</h1>

  <table class="content-table" id="dataTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Row1Cell1
      </td>
      <td>
        Row1Cell2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Row2Cell1
      </td>
      <td>
        Row2Cell2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you. You are a life savior!